# How to build configfs kernel module externally

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I've used the standard `make -C /usr/src/$(uname -r) M=$(pwd) modules` invocation to build many out of tree modules before (`ath`, `e1000e`, etc).

Despite being defined as a tristate (`tristate "Userspace-driven configuration filesystem"`), `configfs` fails to build for me with:

```
sh-4.1# make -C /usr/src/kernels/3.18.17-1 M=$(pwd) V=1 modules
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.18.17-1'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
        echo >&2;                                                       \
        echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
        echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
        echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
        echo >&2 ;                                                      \
```

I've tried and gotten the same results with `3.18.17`, `3.18.25`, and `3.18.27`. Building `ath` and `e1000e` with the same invocation works fine on the same system.

Comment: Do you have an include/generated/autoconf.h and an include/config/auto.conf?

Comment: Well, no, but it is my understanding that that method of building out-of-tree modules is obsolete in modern kernels - other modules build fine out-of-tree without those files being present.